# How to solve an error with curl (security)

Tags: ubuntu, curl

When using curl for opening a website, everything worked fine. 
Until today, when I got this error:
"Security Violation (403)" and "Access denied".

Could you imagine, what the reason for this spontaneous problem could be?
I tried using the "-k" parameter and the "cacert"-parameter, but both options just won't work.

Kind regards,
X3nion

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Error Page</title><style type="text/css">html{font-family:'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:1em}.center-box{margin: 20% auto auto auto;width: 50%;border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;padding: 1em;} </style>                                                                                                            
<title>Security Violation (403)</title></head></head><body> 
<div class="center-box">  
<h3>www.ebay-kleinanzeigen.de&nbsp;|&nbsp;Access denied (403)</h3> 
<h4>Current session has been terminated.</h2>                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
<p>For further information, do not hesitate to contact us.</p> 
<p>Ref: <span id="addr">2003:6:63e3:2d98:8d19:56d:b877:8b2f</span>&nbsp;<span id="time">1590873486</span></p>                                                          
</div></body><script>document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = (new Date()).toISOString()</script>                 </html>
```

Comment: Nothing's spontaneous. Something changed. The trick is to track down what that is. Unfortunately, we cannot possibly tell what that is from here. Where do you "get this error", exactly? What is the precise text? What happens when you try to access the same resource using your web browser? You'll need to narrow it down.

Comment: I added the detailed error above. When opening the website via Firefox, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to try to workaround this problem, is setting the same request headers from a default request made with a browser.

you can access this address in a browser and `copy as curl` in the developer tools (<kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), network tab, and try to do the request again. If it pass, you can use now this new command with all attributes (headers and cookies) from current request.

Here is a way to reproduce this instructions:

[image]

In my example I'm using the browser to access `www.google.com.br`.

Here is the output from this copy (30/05/2020):

```
curl 'https://www.google.com.br/' \
  -H 'authority: www.google.com.br' \
  -H 'pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'upgrade-insecure-requests: 1' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9' \
  -H 'x-client-data: CIm2yQEIprbJAQjBtskBCKmdygEIlcfKARibvsoB' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-mode: navigate' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-user: ?1' \
  -H 'sec-fetch-dest: document' \
  -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' \
  -H 'cookie: SID=xQcxtDTQXD5qliOgo8FsNlkDrKtYI_jrPiJR2ZfyZh_S6rACWTHDFRPceJ1Tlr5vll4Oyg.; __Secure-3PSID=xQcxtDTQXD5qliOgo8FsNlkDrKtYI_jrPiJR2ZfyZh_S6rAC6tkjLmhvnJemQDVkqRXJzA.; HSID=Arao901D7S0l5puo5; SSID=ADCpbatyj1vAsJkQ4; APISID=VFdN0avW09MCGbDg/AfSwcaKj2K-5VAdEp; SAPISID=H6_f7UhMDkCvL5NK/AU2VJW0BtPIm65yd_; __Secure-HSID=Arao901D7S0l5puo5; __Secure-SSID=ADCpbatyj1vAsJkQ4; __Secure-APISID=VFdN0avW09MCGbDg/AfSwcaKj2K-5VAdEp; __Secure-3PAPISID=H6_f7UhMDkCvL5NK/AU2VJW0BtPIm65yd_; NID=204=vxNaEkPbH3XB5fl2OuV-8vZcxKvBqg9d9FRiPCTjZkUMw-row1uJJYuEp7OOJtX7XyAMPjbeo_wWhcl08zcEGI6v1HfRrAx8e8y6pXNQndD8B-FzUwHkFUZ5D-znDzlyGEeZIDOUma9tRg7tQNImG355pJlmUXplzwh2A4HqFugemrGZBmsOlDZoyfnkuXdi-TP75sXHND7eHONxuVBxcioAftLteD6p6_B8YmutQ9DW4fmGO-vDW670jO-Z3xrJrlP9AZGpLgqevJHccRvFhKcHrQtFLGjpnWUL6DUX_Wh03O7QA-Fd5P8gblr1fV8HTEkHXNm8Ts4g3KNV6XeGZXgApfgthCXTZbS29fdcsxgtM5O6nQ; ANID=AHWqTUkfogufuIUy88wEaeh3NUYr_VlBp2vI5oaQxuA-EzjvZKFBNZW-Fu09sowM; 1P_JAR=2020-05-30-21' \
  --compressed
```

Comment: I'm going to try that out. Which browser did you use to export the settings?

Comment: Used chrome. But firefox has the same feature

Comment: Well but the developer edition? Or does it work with the standard version as well?